# Clone row and remove elements then re-add

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone a table row, which works, and then add it to a new row.

The problem I am having is I need to add some dynamic elements into the new row but this should be only for 1 row. If a new row is dynamically added, I want the previous row to remove those elements I added dynamically.

I have tried using the .remove() method but this still shows.

This is what I am doing:

```
var lastTableRow = $('#mainTable tr:last').clone();
lastTableRow.attr('id', 'row_' + rowIDNumericOnly);
$('#mainTable tr:last').after(lastTableRow);

// finally, add a button into this new row:

$('#row_' + rowID + ' td:nth-child(2)').append('<input type="button" ID="cmdGetName_' + rowID + '" value="Fetch CAS Name" onClick="GetName($(\'#Names_' + rowID + '__Number\').val(), ' + CAS+ ')" />');
```

now, when the user presses the "Add row" button, it calls the function/method above to do the same thing. At this point, I want to remove the dynamically added button "cmdGetName_" if it exists when cloned the previous row.

any ideas?

when removing, I am doing the following:

```
 $('#cmdGetName_' + oldRowIDNumericOnly).remove();
```

where oldRowIDNumericOnly is taking the last row added in the table, and getting its ID.
rowIDNumericOnly is the NEW ID (from the previous table row ID and adding 1 to it)

Comment: Why don't you create the button once, and append it to the new row? That will remove it from the old location.

Comment: `.remove()` should have worked, you must have made a mistake in the selector. The easiest way would be to give the button a class, and use `$(".buttonclass").remove()` before adding the new one.

Comment: What I am seeing is that for some reason, it seems to add another button to the new row if the previous row contained a button but doesn't look right or work correctly. I do think the selector is correct.

Comment: Post your code that removes the button. How else can we tell what you did wrong?

Comment: @Barmar - not sure what you mean? I need to copy the previous row which may or may not have a dynamic button injected as per the method above in my post. The next time round they may press the add new row button. The new row will contain a "Find" button, like above which is added dynamically

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. I thought you wanted to remove the button from all the other rows.

Comment: Correct. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are saying... :) so I copy a previous row. I then need to add to this cloned row, a new button. But I want to remove it when they add a new row. The previous row may contain the button already... which I want to remove before injecting it back into the DOM

Comment: What is `oldRowIDNumericOnly`? Your first code uses `rowIDNumericOnly` for the row that you're cloning.

Comment: Right. There are 2 - I will clear that up. oldRowIDNumericOnly is taking the previous table row ID. The rowIDNumericOnly is the new ID (essentially the previous ID + 1)

Comment: Avoid using inline events...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the dynamic input a class, e.g. `class="CmdGetName"`. Then you can do:

```
var oldLastTableRow = $("#mainTable tr:last");
oldLastTableRow.find(".CmdGetName").remove;
var lastTableRow = oldLastTableRow.clone();
```

Comment: LOVE YOU! Thank you. This appears to work on initial inspection.